# How to call controller function from other controller In symfony 3?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I am new in symfony and I want to call base controller function from other controller. main purpose behind is there is Some common process(code) for all controller so I made one common function in base controller so I able to access function from every controller in sonata admin controller as well as other normal controller but I have not any idea about this, can any one know about this then suggest me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just paste your title into the search bar and start reading.  Wanting to call a controller from another controller is a common beginner's mistake.  You seldom need to do so.  Besides reading the answers, take a look at the service container portion of the manual as well as the best practices section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your controller as service, then get it in another controller.

In your services.yml define needed controller as a service:

```
services:
    service_name:
        class: BundleName\Controller\YourControllerName
```

Then in any controller you'll be able to get this service via container:

```
$otherController = $this->get('service_name');
$otherController->methodName();
```

Comment: Thanks For help, it working well in normal controller but In sontata admin controller i put below code then it give me error.
 **********************Code***********************
$BaseController = $this->get('common_fetch_department_details');
return $BaseController->testingAction();
*********************End Code************************

it give me Error:

Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class "AppBundle\Admin\MedicalProviderAdmin".

Please suggest me how to call same service function in sonata admin

Comment: How I can call normal controller function from sonata controller , please suggest me?

Comment: @SandeepGajera please incorporate it to your question or ask another one.

Comment: You should never (AFAIK) call a controller function from another controller. It looks like your controller code should be shared, and this is what services are for. So create one and use it as Mert suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Since Symfony services are now private by default, it's cleaner to inject just the controller you want.

```php
    class AppController extends AbstractController
{
    private ImportService $importService;
    private ParameterBagInterface $bag;
    private BillRepository $billRepository;

    public function __construct(ImportService $importService, ParameterBagInterface $bag, BillRepository $billRepository)
    {
        $this->importService = $importService;
        $this->bag = $bag;
        $this->billRepository = $billRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/app_load", name="app_load")
     */
    public function load()
    {
//        import, or whatever.
```

Now inject the controller.  For example, in the doctrine fixtures loader.

```php
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use App\Services\ImportService;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    private AppController $appController;
    private LoggerInterface $logger;

    public function __construct(AppController $appController, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->appController = $appController;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->appController->load();
        $this->logger->info("Loaded.");
    }
}
```